# Как поставить rosemary на spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Я [отсюда](https://github.com/siegelzero/rosemary) скачал архив и распаковал его в `C:\Users\Elvin\Anaconda3\pkgs\rosemary-master`(я не уверен,что верно выбрал директорию)
В директории шёл файл `setup.py`. Я открыл anaconda prompt и прописал следующую команду:`(base) C:\Users\Elvin\Anaconda3\pkgs\rosemary-master>python.exe setup.py install`. После этого я рассчитывал,что в spyder3 ошибка

```
runfile('C:/Users/Elvin/Documents/тчмк3.py', wdir='C:/Users/Elvin/Documents')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-622a8324d12e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Elvin/Documents/тчмк3.py', wdir='C:/Users/Elvin/Documents')

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_86\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_86\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Elvin/Documents/тчмк3.py", line 234, in <module>
    import rosemary.number_theory.primes.sieves as sieves

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosemary'
```

исчезнет, но она по-прежнему остаётся. Как можно добавить rosemary и мочь запуститься с такими импортами:

```
import itertools
from random import randint
from math import exp, log, sqrt

import rosemary.number_theory.primes.sieves as sieves

from rosemary.number_theory.prime_list import _PRIME_LIST
from rosemary.number_theory.core import (
   gcd,
    integer_nth_root,
    integer_sqrt,
    jacobi_symbol,
)
```